# Function MAX apenas 1 (um) registro no Oracle

Tags: sql, funções, oracle11g

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda no uso da Function MAX() do Oracle???

Preciso fazer uma query que retorne apenas o último registro de uma tabela de histórico, porém preciso que retorne 3 (três) colunas desse registro -> Id, Ticket_id e Queue_id, porém se eu utilizar a query da seguinte forma abaixo a query não é executada devido a um erro no GROUP BY.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para a query rodar devo adicionar a coluna QUEUE_ID no GROUP BY da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas desta forma o resultado não retorna o último registro pelo MAX(ID) e sim retorna 2 registros, conforme abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu preciso apenas do último registro, no caso seria o 53474 com a Queue_id 22.

Alguém sabe como criar esse tipo de query no Oracle?

Comment: Tentou um subselect com max ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumindo que só há uma entrada com o valor máximo da coluna pretendida (para as condições colocadas), pode-se resolver a questão desta forma:

```
SELECT ID, TICKET_ID, QUEUE_ID
FROM TICKET_HISTORY
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT MAX(ID) 
  FROM TICKET_HISTORY
  WHERE HISTORY_TYPE_ID = 27 AND STATE_ID = 2 AND 
  TICKET_ID = 1290
);
```

Comment: Perfeito Andrei, dessa forma funcionou perfeitamente, não havia tentado dessa forma ainda, valeu pela dica.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```
SELECT MAX(ID), TICKET_ID, QUEUE_ID
FROM TICKET_HISTORY
WHERE HISTORY_TYPE_ID = 27 AND STATE_ID = 2 AND TICKET_ID = 1290
ORDER BY TICKET_ID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Isso não resolve o problema, `TICKET_ID` é o valor idêntico em todas as linhas, o `order by` não vai servir muito bem.

Comment: No Oracle não funciona dessa forma com DESC LIMIT 1, já resolvi com a dica fornecida pelo Andrei.